# this.state.[object].map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I bet I am missing something trivial, but for some reason, I am getting

> this.state.iata.map is not a function

, even tho I have binded this context to all functions where I need to use that state. Plus, iata state is an array so I don't see a problem of using map function.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Select, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core/Select';

export default class IATACodesSelect extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            iata: []
        }   

        this.changeIATAState = this.changeIATAState.bind(this);
        this.renderIATACodes = this.renderIATACodes.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.changeIATAState();
    }

    changeIATAState = () => {
        this.setState({iata: this.getIATACodes});
    }

    getIATACodes = () => {
        return JSON.parse("../../assets/iata-codes.json");
    }

    renderIATACodes = () => {
        return this.state.iata.map(data => 
            <MenuItem key={data.response.code}>{data.response.name}</MenuItem>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Select>
                {this.renderIATACodes()}
            </Select>
        );
    }
}
```

VS Code is recognizing both state and map function for that state, which means that code should be ok, but as I said, I am probably missing something trivial and I can't see what.

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: First thing is you don't need to bind this as your functions are arrow functions and second log getIATAcode function maybe you're not getting array

Comment: use {this.renderIATACodes}

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of obvious issues to me.

1. **Why are you not importing the JSON file at the top of your file like this?**
   You can then just use it directly in your render method like this:

```
import iataData from '../../assets/iata-codes.json'
...
return (
  <Select>
    {iataData.map(data => 
      <MenuItem key={data.response.code}>{data.response.name}</MenuItem> 
    }
  </Select>
)
```

And you can ditch the whole state as well as updating the state. It's not necessary. But... if you do need the state, then check below.

2. **You get the error because of this line of code**

```
changeIATAState = () => {
  this.setState({iata: this.getIATACodes});
}
```

You are not actually "calling" the function -> `{iata: this.getIATACodes()}`. So you you can not do `array.map()` on a function reference. `function.map()` doesn't work.

3. **You are not actually parsing the right thing.**

```
JSON.parse("../../assets/iata-codes.json");
```

You are trying to parse the string `"../../assets/iata-codes.json"` which is obviously going to result in an error of type

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 0
```

Hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: This is what I get with first suggestion: Uncaught TypeError: _assets_iata_codes_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.map is not a function

Comment: @Ryukote I see. You need to add a loader or just include the file type to your webpack config that can import the JSON file and parse it right away. Do you have a custom webpack config? Or are you using create-react-app? After that, it will work for sure.

Comment: I am using create-react-app, I didn't touch webpack config once in this project.

Comment: @Ryukote I would need to actually have access to the code to see why this would happen. create-react-app doesn't have any issues with json import. You either don't import the correct file, you don't have array in the JSON base file or there is some messed up config.

Have a look here. It works fine. Try to compare https://codesandbox.io/s/y2ynj96j9z

Comment: Maybe try to import it without the `.json` at the end.

Comment: If you want to have an access to the code, here it is: https://github.com/Ryukote/RJS-Flights/tree/development

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187811/discussion-between-sam-uherek-and-ryukote).

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

in getIATACodes you are parsing the string "../../assets/iata-codes.json", not the actual JSON

do something like this:

```
      getIATACodes = () => {

        fetch("/assets/iata-codes.json")
          .then((res)=> res.json())
          .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
             iata : res
            })
          })
      }
```

Comment: This doesn't help. Error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

this snippet:

```
getIATACodes = () => {
    const { response } = JSON.parse("../../assets/iata-codes.json");
    return response;
}
```

are you sure iata-codes.json is valid  array, e.g.:

```
[
 {id: 1, code: 'code 1'}, 
 {id: 2, code: 'code 2'}
]
```

Comment: I am positive that json is valid array.
This is snippet from that json: https://pastebin.com/epPK6wsT

Answer (score 0):

We can not map object directly. Your problem is in here. You attempt to map to your json object, directly. If you try this,

```
  renderIATACodes = () => {
    let keys= Object.keys(this.state.iata)
    return keys.map(key =>
      <MenuItem key={this.state.iata[key].code}>{this.state.iata[key].name}</MenuItem>
    )
  }
```

your problem will be resolved. And you need to follow steps of @Sam Uherek absolutely.